# sklearn pipeline get_feature_names_out() fails unless dataframe has matching rename?

Tags: scikit-learn

I've been struggling with this for a while, and not sure if it's a bug or I'm misunderstanding something.   I have a simple sklearn (1.3.1) pipeline where the first step is renaming its input features, so I implemented `feature_names_out` as below.

If I fit the pipeline on a numpy array, everything is fine and it reports output feature names as `x0__log`, `x1__log`:

```py
from typing import List
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

def with_suffix(_, names: List[str]):
    return [name + '__log' for name in names]

p = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(np.log1p, feature_names_out=with_suffix),
    StandardScaler()
)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], columns=['a', 'b'])

p.fit_transform(df.values)
p.get_feature_names_out()
```

However if I fit on the dataframe directly with `p.fit_transform(df)`, then `p.get_feature_names_out()` gives me a stack trace ending with `ValueError: input_features is not equal to feature_names_in_`.  We can see that the first step is outputting the expected names `a__log, b__log` but then the second step is using the original column names which causes the conflict:

```py
print(p.feature_names_in_)
print(p[0].get_feature_names_out())
print(p[1].feature_names_in_)

['a' 'b']
['a__log' 'b__log']
['a' 'b']
```

Eventually I realized I could fix it by applying the same renaming to the dataframe columns itself.  For example, using this wrapper both `p.fit_transform(df)` and `p.fit_transform(df.values)` work as expected.

Is this intended?  It seems wrong to rename the features twice?

```py
def wrapped(func):
    def _func(X):
        W = func(X)
        if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            W = W.rename(columns=dict(zip(X.columns, with_suffix(None, X.columns))))
        return W
    return _func


p = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(wrapped(np.log1p), feature_names_out=with_suffix),
    StandardScaler()
)

p.fit_transform(df)
p.get_feature_names_out()
```

Comment: Odd, I wouldn't expect `p[1].feature_names_in_` to even exist.

Comment: Oh! The FunctionTransformer is outputting a dataframe without the decorated names??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `FunctionTransformer` by default applies `func` directly to the input without converting the input first; so `p[0].transform(df)` produces a dataframe with columns still `[a, b]`, and `p[1]` gets fitted on that frame, setting its `feature_names_in_` attribute also to `[a, b]`, which contradicts what comes out of `get_feature_names_out` (having been passed through your `with_suffix`).

Probably this should be opened as an Issue on the scikit-learn github.

In the meantime, you can set `validate=True` in your `FunctionTransformer`: this will convert the input to a numpy array, so that the subsequent step won't be fitted on a dataframe, so won't have a `feature_names_in_` set.

Comment: That makes sense, i'll post an issue on github

Comment: posted as https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/27695